# Double integral polar coordinates, limits of angle

Tags: calculus

We would like to calculate using polar coordinates the double integral of f(x,y)=x^2*y in R, where R is the surface between x+y-2=0,the circle with (0,0) as its center and radius equals to 2 and x>0,y>0.
I used polar coordinates r,t, but I face difficulty in finding the limits of angle t.

I would appreciate for your quidance.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: Try drawing $R$ and see what you get. Substitue $x=rcos\theta$, $y=rsin\theta$ and put them in the inequalities.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the inequality that 2-x<y<sqrt(4-x^2) and then I substituted the expressions you refer. I did this from the beginning, but it is still in much complicated form the result I get in regards with the angle. I would appreciate for your quidance. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ you have to evaluate the integral of the function $f(x,y)=x^2y$ in the domain $E=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x,y\geq 0,y>2-x\text{ and }x^2+y^2<4\}$. 
If you look at the area bounded by these two curves you can observe that it can be obtained by a subtraction of the area defined by the inequality $y>2-x$, which is a triangle, from the area defined by the inequality $x^2+y^2<4$, which is a circular sector.

Let $T$ be the area of the triangle with vertices in $(0,0),(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$, and $C$ the area of the circular sector. Since we have the restriction $x,y\geq0$, we have to consider $C\cap \mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R^+$ and it's easy to see that, applying the polar coordinates' substitution, we get
$$\begin{cases}\rho\cos\theta\geq0\\\rho\sin\theta\geq0\\\rho^2<4\end{cases}\implies\rho \in(0,2)\text{ and }\theta\in(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})\implies$$$$\iint_Ef(x,y)dxdy=\iint_Cf(x,y)dxdy-\iint_Tf(x,y)dxdy=$$$$=\int_{(0,\frac{\pi}{2})}\int_{(0,2)}(\rho\cos\theta)^2\rho\sin\theta\rho d\rho d\theta-\iint_T x^2ydxdy=$$$$=\int_{(0,\frac{\pi}{2})}\int_{(0,2)}\rho^4\cos^2\theta\sin\theta-\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x} x^2ydydx.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, really helpful! Merry Christmas!

Comment: It's a pleasure! I'm glad this helped you. If you don't mind, could you accept my answer? Anyway, Merry Christmas!

Comment: Yes indeed, really Thank you very much!!!